# sudo dpkg i chntpw* is not working

Tags: sudo, dpkg, password-recovery, libgcrypt

I am trying to run `sudo dpkg -i chntpw*` while running Ubuntu from a USB drive on my PC. I get this message.

```
(Reading database ... 169714 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack chntpw_1.0-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chntpw (1.0-1+b1) over (1.0-1+b1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of chntpw:
 chntpw depends on libgcrypt20 (>= 1.6.0); however:
  Package libgcrypt20 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package chntpw (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chntpw
```

I am trying to recover lost password.

Comment: If you have an internet connection, you should be able to  install chntpw from the Ubuntu repository, either using the Software Center or using `sudo apt-get  install chntpw`. Unlike installing via `dpkg`, this will automatically resolve dependencies for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

this should be resolved. But you need to be connected to internet.

Comment: it is asking to remove chntpw? should I do that

Comment: @Newbee What is your Ubuntu version? Are you connected to internet?

Comment: It is 14.04. and yes I am connected to internet

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: Actually I answered both no and yes different times and it does not matter. same issue when I run the sudo command with chntpw

Comment: the update command seems to run but same issue

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install libgcrypt20`. Does it install?

Comment: I get this message E: Invalid operation insall
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install libgcrypt20
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libgcrypt20 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and change download server. You are either not connected to internet or the server you try to download from is down. Does `sudo apt-get update` give errors?

Comment: sudo apt-get update does not give errors. I will try the settings as suggested

Comment: This package `libgcrypt20` is available. It should have been installed automatically, but your system does not see it. Change server to main.

Comment: ok changed back to main